# Git to SVN trouble

Tags: svn, git, perforce

My boss has a Perforce repository for which he wants to make a read-only copy available on Sourceforge via subversion. He had a perl script which would do this but it's no longer functioning (we don't want to try debugging it yet) and it's really not that great anyway.

So an alternate solution is to pull the perforce repo into git as a remote ref, which I have already done successfully (including all the proper commit details and authors), now the trouble I'm having is pushing it out to a separate SVN repository. I can make it start the commit process with "git svn dcommit --add-author-from", but the problem is even though the correct author appears at the end of the commit message the "real" author committing is my machine's user. I want to preserve the real author with the commit, and I'd also like to preserve the original timestamps as well.

Is anyone familiar with how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just publish it as a [Git repository on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Git)?

**Edit:** Well, if you can go with GitHub, they've actually come up with a way to have read and write access to a Git repository [using the SVN client](http://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support). All you have to do is push the repository to GitHub.

Comment: We may end up doing that (or github), but it'd still be nice to support SVN clients since sadly not everyone has git.